# How is a method call resolved if the there are two methods with same name, one marked const and the other not, in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

```
void testMethod(){
  cout<<"Normal Method";
}

void testMethod() const{
     cout<<"Const Method";
}
```

which of these will be called by call to `testMethod()`? When I tried the first was called.
But how is this decided and it can't always be the first, otherwise there is no point in treating these two as different functions.

Comment: If you call it on a `const` object, you get the `const` version... http://ideone.com/f8EA7w

Comment: The `const` more or less corresponds to a `const ClassName * const this` first parameter instead of `ClassName * const this`.

Comment: @chris: might be less confusing if you were putting the `const` always to the right of the object it qualifies. That is: `ClassName const* const this` vs `ClassName* const this`.

Comment: @MatthieuM., True, I generally just prefer it on the left because that's what I'm used to and my brain does a pretty good job of reading it left to right and putting things in place (again because that's what I'm used to). For someone not used to it, though, I agree. Good to start early.

Answer (score 3):

If the member function is called through a reference to `const` or a pointer to `const`, or if it is called directly on an object whose type is `const`-qualified, the overload qualified as `const` will be picked. Otherwise, the overload not qualified as `const` will be picked.

```
X x;
x.testMethod(); // Calls the non-const version
X const& y = x;
y.testMethod(); // Calls the const version
X* z = &x;
z->testMethod(); // Calls the non-const version
X const w;
w.textMethod(); // Calls the const version
```

In more formal terms, paragraph 9.3.2/3 of the C++11 Standard specifies (in the quote, `cv` stands for `const`-or-`volatile`, and you can ignore the `volatile` part for the purposes of your question):

> A *cv-qualified* member function can be called on an object-expression (5.2.5) only if the object-expression is
>   as cv-qualified or less-cv-qualified than the member function [...]

Comment: @user2425443: Glad you found it helpful